# volatile hashmap with intermittent addition of new entries

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I have a use case where I will have a Hashmap which starts out as empty. As the application runs, cache will get filled. Multiple threads will access the entries from the cache concurrently. The entries accessed by the threads will not be modified. These are read-only copies.

But the requirement is that if any particular thread does not find the copy of the object it is looking for in the cache, it will create the object and will add it to the cache. Once that copy is available, it does not have to be created again.

The reason I am thinking of using Volatile Hashmap is, they enforce *happens-before* semantics, hence if the map gets a new entry, all threads will be able to see it. Since the threads won't modify the entries in cache ever, I am hesitant to use ConcurrentHashMap. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sounds to me like a perfect use for `ConcurrentHashMap` - why are you hesitant?

Comment: Your understanding about `volatile` seems to be wrong. `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()` or Guava's `Cache` would be a suitable solution though.

Comment: I am hesitant about using concurrent hashmap is i dont want to incur additional cost of locking records during read which i thought concurrent hashmap can do. My use case mutltiple threads can and will access the same record from the cache and they wont update the record. They will just read the record

Answer (score 0):

No, this would not work how you're expecting. I see this particular view of volatile frequently enough that it is worth examining.

Member references and the types that inhabit them that bear the volatile keyword do not get bestowed any special properties with respect to concurrency outside of two actions:

- volatile read (eg. accessing the field)
- volatile write (eg. assignment to the field)

That's it. And these special actions (17.4.2) only apply to actions on the member field itself, and *not* to any methods that may be called from the stored object.

For example:

```
private volatile List<Foo> foos = null;

private void assign() {
    foos = new ArrayList<>(); // This is a volatile write

    // This mutation is not handled any differently than any other list.
    // It is not special simply because the list referenced happens
    // to be assigned to a volatile. If another thread accessed the
    // field 'foos' it may see an inconsistent state (null, empty list,
    // or possible worse) because this is not thread-safe.
    foos.add(new Foo()); 
}
```

Think of the above mutation instead like this:

```
List<Foo> local = foos; // This is a volatile read, and is specially handled
local.add(new Foo()); // There is no special handling of this mutation
```

So then, what's the point of volatile? Well, as previously stated the only two actions that are treated differently are assigning to a volatile field and accessing a volatile field. A volatile write creates what's called a 'happens-before' relationship with any reads (accesses) of that field in other threads. In short if thread A executes a volatile write to a field, then Thread B  accesses that field it will see it either in it's previous state, or the new state. There will be no inbetween states that Thread B could see the object in, compared to the above example where another thread could see foos in an inconsistent state. You can use this to your advantage:

```
private volatile List<Bar> bars = null;

private void assign() {
    List<Bar> local = new ArrayList<>(); // local copy
    local.add(new Bar());
    bars = local; // Volatile write
}
```

See the difference here is we created an object locally, fully initalized it, and then assigned it to the volatile member. Now, any thread that accesses the field 'bars' will see either null (the previous state) or a fully constructed list with one element. This of course only holds true as long as you don't try to mutate the list in place, and also importantly as long as the list doesn't mutate itself when you call accessor methods.

Also, just use a ConcurrentHashMap.